# BigQuery Weather Public Data Sets - Missing Last Few Days Data

Tags: google-bigquery, weather-api, google-weather-api

I have run some queries against BigQuery public data sets for weather. I have used both GSOD (`bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod2019`)and GHCN (bigquery-public-data.ghcn_d). In both cases, the most recent data I get is from 4 or 5 days ago. Why is that? What can I do to get more recent historic data e.g. this morning or yesterday by lat and long.

Comment: It is a public data set, it has nothing to do with any of your tagged topics.  If you have an issue, it would be best resolved by contacting the provider of the data, not posting here.  Maybe an ETL pipeline broke, maybe the data provider has decided to no longer update the data, maybe the IT guy is on vacation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Those historical datasets are provided by NOAA a few days delayed. For real-time weather, you have to use one of the commercial weather data providers in the Marketplace.